# Oracle PL SQL. Handling division equal to zero exception

Tags: oracle, plsql

I created a trigger, but it's not working.

```
DECLARE
  v_width INTEGER;
  v_height INTEGER := 0;
  v_area INTEGER := 6;
BEGIN
  v_width := v_area / v_height;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('v_width = ' || v_width);
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Division by zero');
END;
/
```

However I always get this error

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01476: divisor is equal to zero
ORA-06512: at line 7
```

I can't debug it . I need to handle it in the right way , all exceptions should be handled.

Comment: v_height is set to 0, why are you trying to divide by number 0?

Comment: As others have pointed out, `v_height` is initialized to zero - the code then divides `v_area` by `v_height` and a `ZERO_DIVIDE` exception is thrown. The exception handler should handle `ZERO_DIVIDE` instead of `NO_DATA_FOUND`. Was there some way in which `v_height` was supposed to be set to a "real" value which you just haven't included? You mention a trigger, but the above isn't a trigger. Perhaps you could edit your question and include the real code for the trigger? Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 2):

```
v_height INTEGER := 0;
v_width := v_area / v_height;
```

`v_height` is always `0`. If you divide by zero you generate an overflow. You need to avoid that.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is to never divide by zero in the first place, e.g.:

```
DECLARE
  v_width INTEGER;
  v_height INTEGER := 0; /*presumably this gets assigned in some other way*/
  v_area INTEGER := 6;
BEGIN
  IF v_height > 0 THEN
    v_width := v_area / v_height;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('v_width = ' || v_width);
  ELSE
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('v_width is undetermined');
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Also, don't handle unexpected exceptions with nothing but a debug output - either protect against them, handle them in a meaningful way, or allow them to propagate to the caller.

Answer (score 2):

Use the predefind exception for division by zero, `ZERO_DIVIDE`:

```
declare
    v_test number;
begin
    v_test := 1/0;
exception when zero_divide then
    dbms_output.put_line('Divide by zero.');
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a user defined exception for divide by zero error(error code = -01476) and use it in your code:

```
declare
  v_width  integer;
  v_height integer := 0;
  v_area   integer := 6;
  e_div_by_0 exception;
  pragma exception_init(e_div_by_0, -01476);
begin
  v_width := v_area / v_height;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'v_width = ' || v_width ) ;
exception
  when e_div_by_0 then
    dbms_output.put_line ( 'Divide by Zero' ) ;
  when no_data_found then
    dbms_output.put_line ( 'No data' ) ;
end;
/
```

Comment: There is a predefined exception for this, ZERO_DIVIDE.

Answer (score -3):

I agree with my colleague , however , I guess you have a little typo . 
Try this :

```
DECLARE
v_width INTEGER;
v_height INTEGER := 0;
v_area INTEGER := 6;
BEGIN
v_width := v_area / v_height;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('v_width = ' || v_width);
EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Division by zero');
WHEN OTHERS THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Division by zero in others exception');
END;
/
```

Good luck !

Comment: NO_DATA_FOUND is not the correct exception, and OTHERS is too generic.